# Hi i am new to React Native, Using Native-base I am trying to design Card View

Tags: react-native, native-base

[image: View will like this][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZFyK0.png)][2][![I am facing problem here inside the Card, able to see description part i am trying to implement its coming below the image actually it suppose to come beside the image
`

```
<ListItem>
                  <Card
                    style={{
                      marginTop: 0,
                      marginBottom: 0,
                      marginRight: 0,
                      marginLeft: 0,
                      borderTopLeftRadius: 8,
                      borderTopRightRadius: 8,
                      flexDirection: 'row',
                    }}>
                     <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                          <CardItem>
                            <Thumbnail
                              source={require('../../assets/images/restaurant_128.png')}
                            />
                          </CardItem>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{flex: 3, flexDirection: 'column'}}>
                          <CardItem>
                            <Body>
                              <Text>{item.Title}</Text>
                              <Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green'}}>
                                {item.Description}
                              </Text>
                            </Body>
                          </CardItem>
                        </View
                      </Card>
                    </ListItem>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
                    <View style={{
                        flexDirection: "row",
                        justifyContent: "flex-start",
                        alignItems: "center",
                        backgroundColor: "#B8B2B2",
                        width: "100%",
                        height: 100
                    }}>
                        <View style={{
                            width: "30%",
                            backgroundColor: "red",
                            height: 100
                        }}>
                            <Text>left image here</Text>
                        </View>
                        <View style={{
                            width: "70%",
                            backgroundColor: "#B8B2B2",
                            height: 100
                        }}>
                            <View style={{
                                flexDirection: "row",
                                justifyContent: "space-between",
                                alignItems: "center",
                                backgroundColor: "#fff",
                                height: 50
                            }}>
                                <View style={{
                                    width: "30%",
                                    backgroundColor: "teal",
                                    height: 50
                                }}>
                                    <Text>lamb samosa</Text>
                                </View>
                                <View style={{
                                    width: "30%",
                                    backgroundColor: "teal",
                                    height: 50
                                }}>
                                    <Text>$4.5</Text>
                                </View>
                            </View>
                            <View style={{
                                width: "100%",
                                backgroundColor: "#B8B2B2",
                                height: 50
                            }}>
                                <Text>Lorem Ipsum</Text>
                            </View>
                        </View>
                    </View>
```